# Panel:Center() is not centring the Derma Frame

Tags: garrys-mod

I've created a Derma Frame, and when I call Center() on that frame it doesn't properly center to the screen.

Screenshot:

[image: 1]]

Here's the code:

```
local ply = LocalPlayer()

hook.Add("OnPlayerChat", "Link:lnotify:OnPlayerChat", function(ply, text, teamChat, isDead)
    if(ply:IsSuperAdmin()) then
        if (text == "!lnotify") then
            local lnotifyAdminMenu = vgui.Create("DFrame")
            lnotifyAdminMenu:Center()
            lnotifyAdminMenu:SetSize(1000, 720)
            lnotifyAdminMenu:ShowCloseButton(true)
            lnotifyAdminMenu:MakePopup()
        end
    else
        Derma_Message("You're not permitted to use this menu", "Access Denied", "OK")
    end
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:Center()` function does set the starting position of the frame in the middle a you can see on your screenshot. I am not sure, but I think that there is no function which automatically centers your frame.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke to a few members on Discord. Credit to XXenix#2334 on Discord for resolving this.

It's actually quite logical. In my code, I'm using the :Center() function, before I've set the size. GLua is setting the position of the frame when the frame is 0px by 0px, and then once the game has set the size, the top left corner is in the center spot.

I hope this can help other newcomers with GLua.